# How can I upgrade Power shell version from 3.0 to 4.0 or 5.0

Tags: powershell, windows-8, version, upgrade, powershell-cmdlet

I am using Windows 8 and the Power shell version is 3.0 but i want to use cmdlet which is not supported PSversion 3.0 so how can i update version 4.0 or more

Comment: Google "download WMF 5.1"

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54616&751be11f-ede8-5a0c-058c-2ee190a24fa6=True

Answer (score 0):

[Download here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ie/download/details.aspx?id=50395&751be11f-ede8-5a0c-058c-2ee190a24fa6=True&e6b34bbe-475b-1abd-2c51-b5034bcdd6d2=True) make sure you have the required dot net framework version.